# PHP MySQL remove quantity

Tags: php, mysql

i met with situation when need to import values with quantity that will be spended many times by some qty.

Eg. i have table with product material

```
ID    TYPE    QUANTITY    SPENT
1     1       10           0
2     1       100          0
```

Now i spent 20 qty of material ONCE and need to update field SPENT to be like this

```
ID    TYPE    QUANTITY    SPENT
1     1       10           10     <--- 0 left
2     1       100          10     <--- 90 left
```

Or i spend 8 qty first then another 20 qty, so table needs to be like this

First - spent 8

```
ID    TYPE    QUANTITY    SPENT
1     1       10           8       <--- 2 left
2     1       100          0       <--- 100 left
```

Second - spent 20

```
ID    TYPE    QUANTITY    SPENT
1     1       10           10       <--- 0 left
2     1       100          18       <--- 72 left
```

So i need to separate spended material quantity by avaible and reduce till limit then reduce other one with avaible qty.

What is the best way for this with php?

Please any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Mysql update is probably what you are looking for.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: Update these 2 values within your code, or create a function or procedure to do the whole spending process.

Comment: do you want to display a separate column for left quantity?

Comment: @Nerfair We don't do that. At least, we don't do it that way... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: @Nerfair Yes i know but don't know how to limit quantity and separate when reach avaible...

Comment: @Smokie i just need to update spent value values after <--- is just notes

Comment: @feroz akbar no that's just notes for reader

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `SPENT` = 10, `QUANTITY` = `QUANTITY` - `SPENT` WHERE `ID` = 1
```

Note that the ID and SPENT fields fields have example values (10 and 1 can be changed, depends on you)

Comment: quantity = quantity -spent will not work cause this spent is the previous spent in the table not the updated one

Comment: @MsiSaurovh, not true, please try it yourself.

Comment: hi @Smokie im not sure that you understeand me perfectly... i know how to deal with update if qty is exact but i need update for overflow... eg. if avaible QTY is 10 and i need to spent 12 to update first by 10 and second by 2 with same type

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE tablename SET SPENT = your_variable, QUANTITY = QUANTITY - your_variable WHERE ID = your_row_id

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for... thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would do this something like this (REQUESTED is number of items requested):

- Start database transaction (to prevent changing spent values by other processes)
- Select one or more rows (you can select all rows if you know there wont be a lot of them. also select only those where QUANTITY > SPENT).
- In PHP start adding SPENT and reduce REQUESTED row by row (if you didn't get all rows previously you need to get new rows as they are needed).
- If REQUESTED is 0 it means you can save all rows do DB and commit transaction, else if REQUESTED > 0 and there no more rows where QUANTITY > SPENT then rollback transaction and inform user that he requested more than its available.